# Использование ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, аннотации, butterknife

Прочитал об аннотациях в Андроиде и наткнулся на такую либу - ButterKnife.

Какая польза от ее использования? Что она дает, кроме того, что заменяет метод findViewById?

Comment: Польза от использования ЛЮБОЙ библиотеки - более простое решение определенных задач. Вместо того, чтобы писать много собственного кода, вы используете библиотеку и количество кода уменьшается в разы. Что дает та или иная библиотека, как правило указано в описании к этой библиотеке. Например, [по ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) - ссылка сюда присутствует на странице проекта в GitHub.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Там не только

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

можно заменить на

```
@InjectView(R.id.button) Button mButton;
```

Но и колбеки инжектить.

Скажем:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

превратится в:

```
@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void onButtonClick() {
  // ...
}
```

В адаптерах упрощается код. Если вы писали свой адаптер для `ListView`, то должны были писать и `ViewHolder` для него. Когда въюх много, то очень не красиво и не удобно в `holder` закидывать элементы. С помощью ButterKnife это просто:

```
static class ViewHolder{
    @InjectView(R.id.image_in_item)
    ImageView image;
    @InjectView(R.id.textview_in_item)
    TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    }
}
```

Если вопрос именно в том, почему именно ButterKnife, а не, скажем, RoboGuice, то он компактнее. RoboGuice тянет много зависимостей и медленнее, ибо он в рантайме, а ButterKnife во время компиляции это делает.

Да и либу написал Jake Wharton. Это тот же, кто писал ActionBarSherlock и другие классные штуки.

**UPD:** как товарищ pavlofff верно заметил, в новых версиях библиотеки `@InjectView` был заменен на `@Bind`, плюс другие изменения были. Лучше смотреть сразу в [репозитории](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: про самое главное - @Bind (и производные) не упомянули :)

Comment: @pavlofff я с Android уже давно не работал, всего и не упомнить )

Comment: В общем то, в новых версиях библиотеки `@InjectView` был заменен на `@Bind` и несколько расширен производными. Не могли бы вы указать об этом в ответе, а то несколько запутывает.

Comment: @pavlofff благодарю за помощь. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Jake Wharton это что-то вроде очень крутого чувака в мире Android?

Comment: @Kostya весьма крутой, да)